# Mockito: Using a List<String> as Parameter

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Currently I write a JUnit Test using Mockito. It should pass when one `String` in the list has a defined value (e.g. `"00123"`):

```
Mockito.when(myMock.isContractAvailable("0815", Arrays.asList(new String[] {ANYVALUE, "00123", ANYVALUE})).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);
```

How can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: try: `Mockito.eq(Arrays.asList(ANYVALUE, "00123", ANYVALUE))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide your custom matcher for argument matching

````
when(myMock.isContractAvailable(eq("0815"), argThat(new ArgumentMatcher<List<String>>() {
        @Override
        public boolean matches(List<String> list) {
            return "00123".equals(list.get(1)); // essentially ```list -> "00123".equals(list.get(1))``` in java 8
        }
})).thenReturn(true);
````

Comment: Thanks! Could you please change this example? I can not use Lambda expressions, because of an old Java version. Thanks.